# A very weird "command not found" error in Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS appeared in the bash terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

In Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, using bash, I got a very weird "command not found" error when entering command from the terminal:

```
sudo apt install strongswan strongswan-swanctl
```

The response from the bash is:

```
sudo apt install strongswan strongswan-swanctl: command not found
```

However, when I try

```
sudo apt install
```

The response is:

```
[sudo] password for jm: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

The bash corresponds as expected.
Then I try:

```
sudo apt install strongswan strongswan-swanctl
```

The response is:

```
sudo apt install strongswan strongswan-swanctl: command not found
```

The same problem went back.
Then I simply try `sudo apt install` again,

```
sudo apt install
```

The response is:

```
sudo apt install: command not found
```

This is truly very weird to me. The same command **corresponded normally** former but **the error "command not found" appeared** later in the same terminal. I'm looking forward to addressing this problem with your help.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the ASCII space (0x20) between words? I'm getting the error when I use a non-breakable space (U+00A0) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response choroba. How could I check whether I use the ASCII space or not?

Comment: @JimmyWhite non-breaking spaces are normally only a problem when the command is copied and pasted (from a website for example) - try typing it out manually

Comment: Yes, that really works. Thank you for your comment steeldriver. I tried typing out the commands manually and it worked in the bash. However, when I copied and pasted commands from the website in FireFox the error appeared. I think it is related to the NBSPs in the website rather than normal SPs. By the way, is there any way to fix this bug in FireFox?

Comment: Not a bug in firefox.  It's a bug in the website.  It's dangerous to copy paste things from websites anyway, as there can be hidden text that gets copied and then you can get surprised when it runs.